# Transparent PNGs lose transparency when uploaded to media library (8.2)

Tags: media-library

I have some PNGs that I created in Photoshop which have transparent backgrounds. I've saved these as PNGs and when I view the images in my file stystem in my browser, the background is transparent as I expect. However, I uploaded them in Sitecore (using the basic Upload File button in the media library) and saved them, but when I place them on my page they have a white background -- I should be able to see the a background image through them, but instead the background is white.

Comment: note - on the media library item, the extension is PNG and the mimetype is image/png

Comment: This works on a clean install of Sitecore for me, at least on the update I have installed (u2 and u6). You should check on a clean install to see if you are still able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Verify you aren’t resizing the images or altering in any other way. You would see these actions in the URL of the image on your web page

Comment: Any css on the placeholder for background-color ?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the image rendering part is not implemented in correct way.
For start with basic you can render the page(consist image) and try to open the image only in new tab(inspect element in browser) and from new open tab try to download the image and see still it is giving you white background or the image is as expected image with transparent background.
If image is with transparent background then you need to do change in the rendering logic of your image.